# How to draw a line in line chart for single value in Charts(IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I need to draw a single value in line chart. Currently i am using ios-charts library for line graph purpose.

The data will be varied some times i'll get the single data inside the data set at that time i need to draw the single value in the line chart.

What i am getting:

[image]

What i required:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share your code as a [example] showing what you have already tried. It’s very difficult to help you otherwise. See also [ask].

Comment: It’s a contradiction to draw a line using only a single point so I am not surprised if the library doesn’t support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library cannot do this automatically, but there is the following option.
You check if your data contains exactly one point. If yes, then you add a so called LimitLine.

For example:

```swift
let limitLine = ChartLimitLine(
   limit: value,
   label: labelText)

limitLine.lineColor = .blue
limitLine.labelPosition = .topLeft
limitLine.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

chartView.leftAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift Charts (Xcode 14 Beta)**

Should someone decide to do something similar with Apple's Swift Charts, RuleMark() can be used to draw the line and PointMark() for a point like this:

```
Chart() {
    RuleMark(
        xStart: .value("Start", 0),
        xEnd: .value("End", 20),
        y: .value("Value", 125)
    )
    
    PointMark(
        x: .value("X Value", 10),
        y: .value("Y Value", 125)
    )
}
```

Example Output:

[image]